# Industrial production of alkali metals

Tags: redox

My professor says that $\ce{Li}$ and $\ce{Na}$ are produced by electrolysis, while $\ce{K, Rb}$, and $\ce{Cs}$ are made via the reaction $\ce{Na + MCl -> NaCl + M}$, where $\ce{M = K, Cs, Rb}$.

I don't understand how the reaction $\ce{Na + MCl -> NaCl + M}$ can take place, given the reduction potentials of the alkali metals ($-3.04, -2.71, -2.93, -2.98,$ and $-3.03$ V for $\ce{Li, Na, K, Rb, Cs},$ respectively). From the data, we see that sodium is the weakest reducing agent and the least electrochemically active among these alkali metals. Why then, would it prefer to displace a more electrochemically active species?

Comment: Note that reduction potentials apply only to water solutions, where ion hydration energy take part in the overall Delta G and E°.

Comment: Don't forget the very high temperatures. The listed electrode potentials in ordinary textbook tables should be restricted to solution phase and ordinary temperatures only.

Comment: Things are somewhat different at elevated temperatures. For example, look up “Potassium” in wiki and see the “Griesheimer process” for reacting KF with calcium carbide.

Comment: @Poutnik do you happen to know what phase the reaction $\ce{Na + MCl -> NaCl + M}$ happens to be? Since it is molten, the standard reduction potentials do not apply?

Comment: @DrPepper Do you see there liquid water at 25 °C ? Standard elchem. potentials includes 3 formal processes: 1/ metal atomization 2/atomic ionization 3/ ion hydration. 3/ is missing above,being replaced by ionic lattice formation.

Comment: The potentials don´t really matter. It is an equillibrium reaction, and the heavier alkalis are removed via distillation, as the have a lower Bp. Afaik, the reduction is done commercially using calcium or barium.

Comment: @DrPepper The standard potentials are only valid for separated electrodes. In a one-pot, especially in a non-aqueous slovent (melt), things can be a *bit* different.

Answer (score 1):

One aspect to consider is that the boiling points of alkali metals go down as they get heavier.
From [The Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/alkali-metal/General-properties-of-the-group):

Lithium:  bp = 1342°C

Sodium:  883°C

Potassium:  759°C

Rubidium:  688°C

Cesium:  671°C

Francium:  677°C (probably this one is merely predicted)

Thus the heavier alkali metals could be volatile enough to effectively escape as vapors while sodium and the chloride salts remain largely liquid.  Thereby the equilibrium that would otherwise limit the displacement of the heavier metal is pulled forward in favor of that metal being lost to the gas phase.  The vapor would later be condensed to get the metal as a solid.